# How to get number of calls for a trace

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-trace

I've added traces to measure execution of some code running on GCP. The traces appear in trace list on StackDriver page and I can see their duration. What I cannot find is number of times reach traces was issued. Where does this number appear?

Comment: Could it be that instead of counting the number of traces (which is the duration of a call) we instead use Stackdriver metrics which will return the number of calls?

Comment: Agree with this sentiment - you can simply write logs for every call and use a log-based metric to count them.

Answer (score 0):

So the comments confirm that StackDriver Trace is not usable for collecting info about number (density) of events along the timeline. I'd expect to get this data from the trace, but will have to find another tools to obtain it.